# using pivot to restructure data in table and dealing with nulls

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains 3 columns. The table stores a countries population at a certain date. Simple example,

```
cen_date country      population 
2010     US           50
2010     Ger          10
2010     UK           5
2011     US           55
2011     Ger          15
2011     UK           10
2011     China        100
```

What I would like to do is have a table like below,

```
       2010      2011
US     50        55
Ger    10        15
UK     5         10
China  NULL      100
```

So you will notice that there was no data for China in 2010 but I would still like this include in the table above but as NULL.

**Update**

Through a bit of trail and error the query below now works

```
select * 
from
(
  select country, cen_date , population
  from Country_Pop    
) org
pivot
(
 max(population)
 for cen_date in ([2009-01-01], [2010-01-01], [2011-01-01])
) piv;
```

Not entirely sure why this work though. I thought I would have to create a list of distinct countries first but guessing it must be something to do with the max and pivot functions?

Comment: yes thanks the query I posted gave me the result I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Find Total no of different years.(Arrange the years in order you want.Add a column if new year found or not)

Step 2. Find all the different countries name.(Just Make them rows, add row if new country found else not)

Step 3. Now fill the datas

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
SELECT
    country,
    [2010] = MAX(CASE WHEN cen_date = 2010 THEN population END),
    [2011] = MAX(CASE WHEN cen_date = 2011 THEN population END)
FROM Test
GROUP BY country
```